# jQuery UI Slider problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, slider

I'm having some problems with the jQuery UI slider widget. I can get the slider itself to work, but it will not slide through any content. You can see the site i'm working on here:
[jquery slider problem](http://www.uconsult.dk/forside.aspx#references)

I want the div with the cyan-bordered boxes to be slided through as you slide with the handler, but I simply can't get it to work. This is the mark I'm using at the moment:

```
<div id="content-scroll" class="reference-scroller">
<div id="content-holder" class="reference-content">
  <div id="content-slider"></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="content-item">test1</li>
    <li class="content-item">test2</li>
    <li class="content-item">test3</li>
    <li class="content-item">test4</li>
    <li class="content-item">test5</li>
     .....
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And the slider plugin is started up like this:

```
$("#content-slider").slider({
animate: true,
change: handleSliderChange,
slide: handleSliderSlide
});

function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
{
var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
$("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide(e, ui)
{
var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
$("#content-scroll").attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}
```

Has anyone got a suggestion for this? :-) Any input is greatly appreciated!

All the best,

Bo

Comment: Hej BO - you need to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uconsult.dk%2Fforside.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) your HTML - you have multiple heads and such

Comment: Hi mplungjan :) Thanks a lot - that was because I was lazy and did a head tag for some styling. Will def. look into validating it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the flaw! :-)

jQuery 1.6.1 distinguishes between attr() and prop(), so I changed:

```
function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
{
    var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
    $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide(e, ui)
{
    var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-    scroll").width();
    $("#content-scroll").attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}
```

To:

```
function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
{
    var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").prop("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
    $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide(e, ui)
{
    var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").prop("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
    $("#content-scroll").prop({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}
```

And now it works just as it should!

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time!! The slider broke when i upgraded to a new version of jquery! thanks again!